# Ruby on rails error goes on refreshing the browser

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am stuck with this weird problem. This problem is only in the production server, at local server it works fine.

I checked my production log and found that the error was at line:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass)

But when I refresh the browser the error was gone and page loads normally. I am not sure what was making the error.

Here is my log:

```
Started GET "/advertisements" for 182.93.88.6 at 2013-07-13 23:47:39 -0700
Processing by AdvertisementsController#index as HTML
  Rendered shared/_profile_menu.html.erb (37.8ms)
  Rendered advertisements/index.html.erb within layouts/application (38.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass):
    4:       <div class="six columns">
    5:         <ul class="breadcrumbs hide-for-small">
    6:           <li><a href="<%= root_url%>">Home</a></li>
    7:           <li class="current">
    8:               <% if current_user %>
    9:               <%= link_to "#{current_user.full_name unless current_user.full_name.nil?}", user_path(current_user) %>
    10:               <% else %>
  app/views/shared/_profile_menu.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_shared__profile_menu_html_erb__3873584509912802681_40734020'
  app/views/advertisements/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_advertisements_index_html_erb___4140482918641285695_46665240'


Started GET "/advertisements" for 182.93.88.6 at 2013-07-13 23:47:41 -0700
Processing by AdvertisementsController#index as HTML
  Rendered shared/_profile_menu.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered advertisements/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_top_link.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_logo.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (6.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_popups.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 14.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

I am using devise for managing user login and full_name is set to accessible attribute in the user.rb Model as:

```
attr_accessible :full_name
```

The server environment is set with nginx, unicorn, capistrano and mysql database. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there has been some sort of Server problem. I redeployed the application and everything worked fine.